# repo sync fails (73/221

Tags: android

i have a problem using repo.
i downloaded virtualbox and installed in on windows 7 host where the guest OS is ubuntu 11.10.
i followed the instructions http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.
unfortunately when doing repo sync i keep getting the following problem:

```
Fetching projects:  33% (73/221)  error: Cannot fetch platform/bootable/bootloader/legacy
error: Cannot fetch platform/bionic
Exception in thread Thread-78:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/nir/WORKING_DIRECTORY/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 186, in _FetchHelper
    current_branch_only=opt.current_branch_only)
  File "/home/nir/WORKING_DIRECTORY/.repo/repo/project.py", line 926, in Sync_NetworkHalf
    if alt_dir is None and self._ApplyCloneBundle(initial=is_new, quiet=quiet):
  File "/home/nir/WORKING_DIRECTORY/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1463, in _ApplyCloneBundle
    exist_dst = self._FetchBundle(bundle_url, bundle_tmp, bundle_dst, quiet)
  File "/home/nir/WORKING_DIRECTORY/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1527, in _FetchBundle
    raise DownloadError('%s: %s ' % (req.get_host(), str(e)))
DownloadError: android.googlesource.com: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> 

error: Couldn't resolve host 'android.googlesource.com' while accessing https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libpcap/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
error: Couldn't resolve host 'android.googlesource.com' while accessing https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libphonenumber/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libpcap/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libphonenumber/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/libpcap
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/libphonenumber

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

does anyone knows what's the problem?

thanks for your help
nir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the network adapter from NAT to "bridged adapter" in VirtualBox's network settings.

Also see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/aU-TQs6B-kU

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the DNS-related error that you've encountered [`error: Couldn't resolve host`] is detailed on the **Known Issues** resolution page at Google's [AOSP Developer Site](http://source.android.com/source/known-issues.html#difficulties-syncing-the-source-tree-dns-issues). Apply this fix by adding the appropriate host entry for your remote repository `android.googlesource.com` inside your development machine's `/etc/hosts` config file. Begin by [clicking here](http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=android.googlesource.com&type=1&server=67.222.132.213&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000&go.x=20&go.y=18) to execute the IP address lookup tool provided by the free web resource: http://network-tools.com/nslook/.

Google's full description of this issue with detailed resolution I've included here:

> > **Difficulties syncing the source tree (DNS issues).**
> >
> > **Symptom**: When running repo sync, the process fails with various errors
> >     related to not recognizing the hostname. One such error is 
> >     `<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>`.
> >     *EDIT: Another lookup error might be* `error: Couldn't resolve host`.
> >
> > **Cause**: Some DNS systems have a hard time coping with the high number
> >     of queries involved in syncing the source tree (there can be several
> >     hundred requests in a worst-case scenario).
> >
> > **Fix**: Manually resolve the relevant hostnames, and hard-code those
> >     results locally.
> >
> > > You can resolve them with the nslookup command, which will give you
> > >       one numerical IP address for each of those (typically in the "Address"
> > >       part of the output).

```
    $ nslookup googlesource.com
    $ nslookup android.googlesource.com
```

> > You can then hard-code them locally by editing /etc/hosts, and adding two
> >     lines in that file, of the form:

```
    aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd   googlesource.com
    eee.fff.ggg.hhh   android.googlesource.com
```

> > Note that this will only work as long as the
> >     servers' addresses don't change, and if they do and you can't connect
> >     you'll have to resolve those hostnames again and edit etc/hosts
> >     accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem ,so I read the download tutorial again ,and solve now.
see below:

The first step is to create a password from [the password generator](https://android.googlesource.com/new-password) and to save it in ~/.netrc according to the instructions on that page.you need have a google account.

The second step is to force authenticated access, by using the following manifest URI: https://android.googlesource.com/a/platform/manifest. say:

$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/a/platform/manifest

then say:
$ repo sync 
it would start download everything

Hope it could help u